# Will mutable reference extract from Option<T> gone after "while let" scope ended?

Tags: rust

I am writing an binary searching tree in Rust, and when I come to removing element from tree, I got problem for multiple mutable references.

Here is the code:

```rust
use std::cmp;
use std::cmp::Ordering;

type Root<T> = Option<Box<Node<T>>>;

struct Node<T: cmp::Ord> {
    data: T,
    left: Root<T>,
    right: Root<T>,
}

pub struct BinTree<T: cmp::Ord> {
    size: i32,
    root: Root<T>,
}

impl<T: cmp::Ord> BinTree<T> {
    pub fn remove(&mut self, data: T) {
        let mut curr = &mut self.root;

        while let Some(ref mut node) = curr {
            curr = match data.cmp(&node.data) {
                Ordering::Less => &mut node.left,
                Ordering::Greater => &mut node.right,
                Ordering::Equal => break,
            };
        }

        if let Some(_) = curr {

        }
    }
}
```

And I got erorr says

```
error[E0503]: cannot use `*curr` because it was mutably borrowed
  --> src/lib.rs:53:16
   |
45 |         while let Some(ref mut node) = curr {
   |                        ------------ borrow of `curr.0` occurs here
...
53 |         if let Some(_) = curr {
   |                ^^^^^^^
   |                |
   |                use of borrowed `curr.0`
   |                borrow later used here

error: aborting due to previous error
```

But that `ref mut node` should be local to `while let` scope right? Why would it be a problem to make more mutable reference after `while let` block ended?

I just want to do something like bellow to remove a node from this binary tree

```rust
if let Some(node) = curr {
    match (node.left, node.right) {
        (Some(_), Some(_)) => {
            node.data = BinTree::pop_min_from(&mut node.left);
            // get minimum data from left most node
            // and drop that node by taking ownership of it
        },
        (Some(left), None) => {
            curr.replace(left);
        },
        (None, Some(right)) => {
            curr.replace(right);
        },
        (None, None) => {
            curr.take();
        },
    }
    self.size -= 1;
}
```

But I found it very complecated to get around with ownership in this case. My brain can't take it, I can't even make sure I do the right thing in `if let` to deal with target node.

Comment: Actually, why don't you do your remove inside the match ?

Comment: @Stargateur Well, I originally did, but I found out that I don't really understand what happen when I mess with all those ownership. To make it logically clearer for me, I take all cleaning work out of first match /cry. And for your code just now, all I was thinking was "How did this work? What is it? What happened? Who am I?"

Comment: I use `&mut Option< Box<Node<T>> >` in my code, but not `Option<&mut Box<Node<T>>>`, and this add difficulty to my toy program. Using wrong kind of indirection maybe.

Comment: well no when I try to fix your compile error I didn't really look what you wanted to do, to remove a node you obviously need something like `&mut Option` but like I said Rust is not the right language for linked list. You are using the wrong tool to implement a binary tree in Rust, I would advice to use something like a vector.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, now I finally know the feeling to use a wrong tool for the right job.